# How would I make it so it only displays the top ten most highest id results?

Tags: php, pdo

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM chatbox");
$result->execute();

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$username = $row['username'];
$message = $row['message'];
echo $username, ' - ', $message, '<br>';
}
?>
```

So basically, this is my code I am using for a chat-box system, I want to make it so that the top ten most highest chat_id results are displayed, and that it automatically keeps updating the ten highest.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM chatbox
```

->

```
SELECT * FROM chatbox ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Would this select the ten highest?

Comment: In your question you asked for "the top ten most highest id results". If this is what you want, yes it will.

Comment: If you're using MySQL